# why I can't use where() and orderby() same time in flluterfire

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I added a Stream to my widget but when I add orderby() and where() same time the the following AssertionError occured:

The Widget:

```
child: StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(currenUserUid)
      .collection("chat")
      .where('modlerUid', whereNotIn: _user.blockedList)
      .orderBy("time", descending: true)
      .snapshots(),
```

> Exception has occurred.
> _AssertionError ('package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart': Failed assertion: line 489 pos 13: 'conditionField == orders[0][0]': The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([time]), true]][0][0]" has to be the same as the where() field parameter "FieldPath([modlerUid])" when an inequality operator is invoked.)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite explicit: in order to use a `whereNotIn` clause, you first must have an `orderBy` on that same field. So:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("users")
  .doc(currenUserUid)
  .collection("chat")
  .orderBy("modlerUid")
  .where('modlerUid', whereNotIn: _user.blockedList)
  .orderBy("time", descending: true)
  .snapshots(),
```

This means that your results will **first** be ordered on `modlerUid` and only then on `time`. This is because of Firestore's querying model, and there's no way to configure it differently.

If you want the results to be in `time` order *and* filter with `whereNotIn` on modlerUid, you will have to reorder the results in your application.

To learn more about how Firestore executes queries, and why this may lead to certain limitations you're not used to from other databases, I recommend watching the [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) series - specifically the episode on [How do queries work in Cloud Firestore?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=2)